# Automatic tests of click events

Tags: testing, google-analytics

Clicks on certain DOM elements sents click events to Google Analytics, as URL requests like `https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/r/collect?v=1&aip=1&t=dc&_r=3&tid=UA-1234567-2&cid=297722160.1523959944&jid=2028321276&_gid=1320758195.1530624077&gjid=12698493&_v=j68&z=1135539045`

What tools/methods/workarounds are usual to automatically test click events - mainly their status code and content?

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure that I understand your question.  First think you should understand is that hits sent to google analytics are not validated they are send and forget.  Google analytics returns a gif thats it there is no way to know if the request was a success or a fail.

There is one way of debugging hits being sent to Google analytics in test before you actually release to production and thats the debug endpoint

> **https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect**?v=1&aip=1&t=dc&_r=3&tid=UA-1234567-2&cid=297722160.1523959944&jid=2028321276&_gid=1320758195.1530624077&gjid=12698493&_v=j68&z=1135539045

sending your hit to the debug endpoint results in

```
{
  "hitParsingResult": [ {
    "valid": true,
    "parserMessage": [ {
      "messageType": "INFO",
      "description": "IP Address from this hit was anonymized to 185.128.103.0.",
      "messageCode": "VALUE_MODIFIED"
    } ],
    "hit": "/debug/collect?v=1\u0026aip=1\u0026t=dc\u0026_r=3\u0026tid=UA-1234567-2\u0026cid=297722160.1523959944\u0026jid=2028321276\u0026_gid=1320758195.1530624077\u0026gjid=12698493\u0026_v=j68\u0026z=1135539045"
  } ],
  "parserMessage": [ {
    "messageType": "INFO",
    "description": "Found 1 hit in the request."
  } ]
}
```

This hit was not actually sent to google analytics it was just test sent.  If you want to set up some kind of unit testing or atuomation testing of your hits your going to have to do that yourself using the debug endpoint

More info can be found here [validating-hits](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/validating-hits)

Comment: Could you explain, what kind of debug response what i get on using analytics_debug.js?

Comment: Its the same https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/debugging